# Opening a URL with xdg-open using Mozilla Remote Protocol

Tags: freedesktop, xdg-open

Older versions of Netscape and Mozilla (for X11) supported the so-called *remote protocol*: it was possible to open a URL or start composing an e-mail whenever a Netscape/Mozilla window (not necessarily from a local process) was open on the current `DISPLAY`.

The "remote" feature worked either way: either from a remote client to a local browser, or vice versa, or even from a remote `host1` to a remote `host2`, provided both could connect to the local `DISPLAY`.

Here's the documentation for:

- [Netscape 4.x](https://web.archive.org/web/20020409100519/http://home.netscape.com:80/newsref/std/x-remote.html)
- [Mozilla Suite](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/remote.html)

Rudimentary support for remote requests has been preserved in [SeaMonkey](https://seamonkey-project.org/), too, so even nowadays it supports arguments like `openURL(%url%,new-tab)` and `openURL(%url%,new-window)`

Now, I want to create a custom `*desktop` file which would launch *SeaMonkey* with exactly those arguments.

The problem is, in this form:

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=seamonkey %u
```

`%u` expansion works, while in this one:

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=seamonkey -remote openURL(%u)
```

it doesn't: `%u` gets expanded **only** if it's surrounded with spaces.

The [desktop entry specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html) doesn't mention this, so this is both an undocumented and unexpected behaviour.

Can you suggest any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot say anything about the specification but as far as just the result matters I (not being familiar with the quoting in such files, though) would expect this to work:

```
Exec=bash -c 'echo seamonkey openURL"($1)"' seamonkey-wrapper %u%
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, except that it doesn't work, either, because the specification has completely mind-blowing escaping and quotation rules not followed by `xdg-open`. Looking at `xdg-open` source code, I wonder whether this piece of ... software has actually undergone any testing.

Comment: @Bass If you find out what the arguments are when the process is called then we may get that "fixed". You could use `strace` or perhaps a wrapper script `Exec=/wrapper/script.sh ...` which just does this: `a=("$@"); declare -p a >/log/file`

Comment: Thank you. I can write a wrapper script which can do whatever I want and even make me a coffee. But I'd be happier if the developers of `xdg-utils` did their job and fixed their own code. Filed bugs [#173](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/issues/173) and [#174](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/issues/174).

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem recently and there is a specification. [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html)

If the `%` is for the application, you need to put `%%`. That is for the future, when creating a .desktop file for youtube-dl and using the `--output` option. In your case you probably need to escape the braces. `\(\)`, because the shell evaluates them. Set the option `terminal=true`, you will see an error about/at `(`.

Or try:
`seamonkey 'openURL(%u)'`
`seamonkey "openurl\$'0028'%u\$'0029'"`

Beware! I use to have problems with `'`, while `"` works. But only `'` means literal without any interpretation/expansion. IIRC, you do not need to put quote the variable, as it will already be quoted.

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestions only apply to POSIX shell, not for `xdg-open` adn `*.desktop` files. As I said, the problem is not parentheses being misinterpreted by the shell but, instead, `%u` not expanded (which seems an undocumented limitation of `xdg-open`). Unfortunately, none of your recipes work for me.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Neither did you mention xdg-open, nor is it a shell. But the xdg-open command/script will be executed in one. POSIX has nothing to do with it. My solution should work, but i am not on my PC and i dont care. My answer just clearifies.

Comment: The question has been originally tagged `xdg-open`. Second, `%u` expansion only makes sense in the context of `xdg-open`. Third, the question has a link to the desktop file specification. So I though it was perfectly clear what the question was about.

Comment: Got me there. I usuay dont look at the tags. I'd say many dont do and expect everything within the post. Anyway, let me give you one thing on your way; xdg-open is the terminal binary/script. The desktop environment implements the xdg standard itself, thats what the specification is for. So, your question is about .desktop files and that to what the variables belong.

Answer (score 0):

The variable pattern usage with leading and trailing percentage characters looks very DOS-ish to me, the references freedesktop specification document only mentions leading characters.

According to the documentation of the [Mozilla Remote Control option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-remote_remote_command), the command `openURL` is an argument to the option `-remote`. Running the Exec command line from shell does not work without this option. Tested successfully with seamonkey 2.49.5 on fedora.

Mind to try out `Exec=seamonkey -remote openURL(%u)`?